# Cant figure out how to properly use memset inside of my DLL

Tags: c++

What I'm trying to do is **write an integer (-1, to be exact) to the address provided by the pattern scan preferably using memset or memcpy** which is returned by the pattern scanner as a **DWORD**

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "memory.h"

DWORD paranoid = sigScan("\x00\x00\x70\x41\x01\x00\x00\x00","xxxxxxxx");

void initiate() {
std::cout<<paranoid<<std::endl;
memset(paranoid,-1,8);//were I'm having issues at (I don't understand this function)
std::cout<<"toggled paranoid"<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Without doing your homework for you, you will need to: (1) convert `paranoid` from an integer into a pointer;  then (2) declare an integer with value `-1` and use `memcpy` to copy that integer into the space being pointed to by the pointer you made in step (1).

Comment: "I don't understand this function": [here you go](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset)

Answer (score 0):

> void * memset ( void * ptr, int value, size_t num );

So you have to write something like that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "memory.h"

void* paranoid = (void*)sigScan("\x00\x00\x70\x41\x01\x00\x00\x00","xxxxxxxx");

void initiate() {

if(paranoid)
    memset(paranoid,-1, sizeof(int));//were I'm having issues at (I don't understand this function)
std::cout<<"toggled paranoid"<<std::endl;
}
```

Also its worth pointing out, that use of the `DWORD` variable to store pointer is potentially unsafe, because it could lead to the pointer truncation in the x64 environment.

Comment: While the second argument is specified as `int`, memset really writes bytes. Now here it may work: -1 is `0xFFFFFFFF` which happens to be indistinguishable from `0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF`.